# How to add all table columns values to the Hasthable using selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am new in Selenium Webdriver. I want to get all Value from a html Table with 2 column and add them in a Hashtable. I don't know where to begin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try some stuff with yourself??

Comment: try with [findElements](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements)

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var hashTable = new Hashtable();
        var table = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("table"));
        int rowCount = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")).Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            hashTable.Add($"row{i}", table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))[i].Text);
        }
```